# Usage of "I wish… so that…"

Tags: conditionals, wish

Is it natural when I write:

***"I wish Lan knew my phone number so that she could call me."***

***"I wish Lan had known my phone number so that she had called me."***

I'm not sure if I can combine a wish sentence and the conjunction "so that" like this. Also, I want to make sure that using "could" instead of "can" and  "had called" instead of "called" in the above sentences are correct.

Thank you all so much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The first one is perfectly fine, the second would be more natural as "...so that she **could have** called me".

(The first sentence wishes she had the ability to call you now, so it makes sense for the second to wish that she had had that ability at some moment in the past.)